How to launch Android Gemini app with an initial query
From my app, I'd like to be able to launch the new Google Gemini android app (as installed from the app store) and provide an initial query/question. I'm currently able to launch the app, but I can't find any information on if there is an intent extra that is supported. I'm able to accomplish this with both ChatGPT and Copilot using a url with a query parameter for the initial question.
Here is my current code for launching Gemini:
val pkg = "com.google.android.apps.bard"
val act = "com.google.android.apps.bard.shellapp.BardEntryPointActivity"
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).apply {
    setClassName(pkg, act)
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
}
if (text != null) {
    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, datextta) // doesn't work
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", text) //doesn't work
}

if (intent.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null) {
    activity.startActivity(intent)
}

Edit:
I am of the understanding that it has long been impossible to provide a query/command to google assistant. Given that Gemini is a replacement for the traditional assistant, I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't supported. I had hope because:

Gemini is installed as a separate app.
When you ask Google Assistant a question, it opens the Gemini app with your question provided. However, the intent that it is using for that action I don't have permission to execute myself.

